# Finding mass attached to the string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, oscillators, string

I'm given the following problem:

> One end of a string with a linear mass density of 7.60* 10^-4 is connected to an oscillator with a frequency of 50.0 Hz. The other end is connected to a hanging variable mass. The string passes over a pulley, and the string between the oscillator and the pulley can vibrate freely. 
>   The length of the vibrating section of the string is 0.500 m. What mass must be attached so that the string vibrates with
>
> i) one antinode between the pulley and oscillator and
>
> ii) three antinodes between the pulley and the oscillator?

I'm given solution for this problem and the part that confuses me a lot is this: 

 i) In this case, the fundamental frequency is excited, so m = 1. We can calculate tensions as follows... 

 And then they calculate tension and from there T = mg they find mass.

 For ii) they are doing the same, except it is third fundamental frequency that is excited, so m = 3.

So, **my questions are:**

1. What does it mean for a frequency to be excited?
2. Why is m = 1 for the fundamental frequency and m = 3 for the third fundamental frequency? And why are they finding another mass if they have these 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) What does it mean for a frequency to be excited?

That's unfortunate wording. I would say that the string was vibrated sinusoidally at a frequency. The string is being "excited", not the frequency.

> 2) Why is m = 1 for the fundamental frequency and m = 3 for the third fundamental frequency? And why are they finding another mass if they have these 1 and 3.

Another unfortunate choice. The m=1 and m=3 items are specific integers referring to the number of antinodes in the standing wave (or resonant wave), not masses. It would be better to use a different letter, such as n or k. n=1 yields the lowest **resonant** frequency for the string and is defined to be *the* fundamental frequency.

There is no such thing as the **third fundamental**. It is properly called the 3rd partial or second overtone. Because the standing wave wavelengths of a string fixed at both ends form a harmonic series ($\lambda,\frac{\lambda }{2},\frac{\lambda }{3},\frac{\lambda }{4}, ...$), the frequencies are referred to as harmonic frequencies, and n=3 (m=3 for your problem) is the third harmonic.